# How to display favorite Promoted link?

Tags: sharepoint-online, promoted-links

My scenario:

I am using a modern a modern page in SharePoint online. I want to display a list of promoted link but i want to be able to let user to mark their favorite link so that they don't need to search for it in the big list each time.

Note each user will have to see only the favorites link they choose

Is there a way to or a solution close to that?

Answer (score 1):

Saddly promoted links or list views are still not available in modern experience,

in classic experience you can do the following:

create a promoted link view on SP designer 
(just create a view in sp designer, the default option is the promoted links view)

once there you will add a filter in SP (somethinkg like title contains empty)

open and close sp designer (to refresh your new view) 
open the view and replace the filter with the following one :

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='LikedBy' />
    <Value Type='Integer'>
      <UserID />
    </Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

now this view will display only the links liked by the user

Comment: for the last part where should i add that code. Should i have a column name LikedBy?